# How to block npm install in nested workspace folders?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I'm using [npm workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces).

So the app's structure is

```
.
+-- package.json
 -- packages
   +-- a
   |    -- package.json
    -- b
        -- package.json
```

The `npm install` script should be executed from the root folder.

But it is still possible to run `npm install` from `a` or `b` folders. Which is should not be allowed.

Is that a way to prevent that possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Can we do this in Package.json?

```
"scripts": {
    "i": "echo \"Error: NPM Install was not allowed, please update Package.json\" && exit 1",
    "install": "echo \"Error: NPM Install was not allowed, please update Package.json\" && exit 1",
},
```